# In GraphQl dot net how we can get projected field names from ResolveFieldContext

Tags: graphql-dotnet

I am new in Graphql and using graphql-dotnet in my asp.net core project.
Consider I have written a query like following.

`restaurants {
    id
    name
  }`

Now I want to get this field names from `ResolveFieldContext`. Is there any way to get this filed names?

Expecting your valuable help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/903
The solution is we need to use `SubFields` to get projected fields